# comparing user entered info to an object array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, comparison

I'm writing a program that simulates an ATM. I'm working on the login function, but I'm lost about how to compare the user entered pin code and account number to the object array, which contains account information for three different users. How would I compare the user entered info to the array? Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Account
{
private:
    int accountNum;
    string accountPin;
    double balance;
    void setPin(string accPin)
    {
        accountPin = accPin;
    }
    void setAccountNum(int accNum)
    {
        accountNum = accNum;
    }
    
public:
    Account() //default constructor
    {
        accountNum = -1;
        accountPin = -1;
        balance = 0.0;
    }

    Account(int accNum, string accPin, double bal)
    //overloaded construtor
    {
        accountNum = accNum;
        accountPin = accPin;
        balance = bal;
    }

    void setAccountBalance(double bal) //balance setter
    {
        balance = bal;
    }
    
    int getAccountNum() //acc balance getter
    {
        return balance;
    }
    
    bool confirmPin(string accPin, int accNum, Account account[]) //login
    {
        bool pinLogin = false;
        
        cout << "LOGIN\nEnter Account#: " << endl;
        cin >> accNum;
        cout << "Enter pin#: " << endl;
        getline(cin, accPin);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            //array comparison
        }
        
    }
    void updateBalance()
    {
        double deposit;
        cout << "Enter deposit: \n";
        cin >> deposit;
        balance = deposit + balance;
        cout << "New balance: " << balance << endl;
    }
    
};

int main()
{
//misc values
    const int size = 3;
    int option;
    
//accounts array
    Account account[size] =
    {
      { 123, "abc123", 100.00 },
      { 456, "def456", 50.00 },
      { 789, "ghi789", 500.63 } 
    };
    
//menu do while loop, unfinshed
    do
    {
        
        cout << "1. Check balance\n2.Make a deposit\n3.Logout\n";
        cin >> option;
        
        switch (option)
            
            case 1: //check balance case
            
            case 2: //make a deposit case
            {
                Account makeDeposit;
                makeDeposit.updateBalance();
                return 0;
            }
    } while (option != 3);
    return 0;
}
```

The comparison starts at the function confirmPin, and the array of user info is initialized in main. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Rethink `Account makeDeposit;` This isn't going to update an existing account, it'll make a new one, update it, and then let it go out of scope.

Comment: Before you can check an `Account` to match the pin, you must first find the `Account`. Don't try to do this as a non-`static` member function, because that implies you have already found the `Account`. Instead ad a new function that gets an account number and finds the matching `Account` in the array. Once you have the `Account`, you can ask for a PIN and use `confirmPin` to confirm that the PIN matches.